# Camera : setDisplayOrientation function is not working for Samsung Galaxy ACE with Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, samsung-mobile, portrait

I was trying to create a simple camera application for research.
I Read [Android Camera Official Document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) and then started coding.
so I did some steps to get it work

1.Added required permissions for Camera feature in app.

2.locked my activity to PORTRAIT mode only.

> setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

3.Added several camera callbacks to get my camera works.

- SurfaceHolder.Callback,
- Camera.PreviewCallback
- AutoFocusCallback
- ShutterCallback
- PictureCallback for RAW image data
- PictureCallback for JPG image data

4.In **surfaceChanged** method I am customizing camera settings.
and so far I got working this for almost all android devices

- LG
- Spice
- Samsung
- HTC
- Micromax
- Sony
- Motorola
- Google Nexus series.

**But** then I tested on **Samsung Galaxy ACE** with Android Version 2.3.6
and found Camera Display Preview is Rotated to landscape mode.

So after putting log-cat/break points I come to know that below methods are not working for this particular model

```
//This method is not working for Samsung Galaxy ACE
 camera.setDisplayOrientation(90); 
//or 
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
//or
parameters.setRotation(90);
```

**Note:** *I Hunted bunch of solutions over Google and SO as well but so far didn't get any luck in this*

- Issus reported [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1193)
- [android camera surfaceview orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157984/android-camera-surfaceview-orientation)
- [Android portrait locked Camera Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251984/android-portrait-locked-camera-preview)
- [Android - Camera preview is sideways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways)
- [Android camera rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309029/android-camera-rotate)
- [Android: Camera preview Rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278155/android-camera-preview-rotated)
- [How to set Android camera orientation properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645960/how-to-set-android-camera-orientation-properly)

For your reference My sample code is below

```
@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        Log.v(TAG, "surfaceChanged get called");

        if (previewing) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }

        if (camera != null) {
            try {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();

                Camera.Size result = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
                    result = (Size) sizes.get(i);
                    Log.i("PictureSize", "Supported Size. Width: "
                            + result.width + "height : " + result.height);

                    if (result.width == 640) {
                        parameters.setPreviewSize(result.width, result.height);// 640*480
                        parameters.setPictureSize(result.width, result.height);
                    } else {

                    }
                }


                //**************************************************************//

                /* 
                 * Here is the logic I have added to Manage Camera Display Orientation
                 *  It checks Current Orientation and SDK and then rotate display to make it Portrait view.
                 */
                int currentSDKVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                Log.d(TAG, "currentVersion " + currentSDKVersion);

                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    if (currentSDKVersion != 7) {

                        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                         parameters.setRotation(90);
                    } else {
                            parameters.setRotation(90);

                        /*
                         * params.set("orientation", "portrait");
                         * params.set("rotation",90);
                         */
                    }
                } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    if (currentSDKVersion != 7) {

                        camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                    } else {

                        parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
                        parameters.set("rotation", 90);

                    }
                }


                //**************************************************************//

                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                camera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
                camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(cameraPreviewCallback);
                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

My Camera Activity (MainActivity.java) Full code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
        OnClickListener {

    public static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";
    private Context context = null;
    Camera camera = null;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView = null;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = null;
    boolean previewing = false;
    private LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;
    private Button buttonTakePicture = null;
    //private TextView textViewResultInfo = null;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate get called");

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //textViewResultInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResultInfo);
        context = this;

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

        buttonTakePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
        buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

        Log.v(TAG, "surfaceCreated get called");
        camera = Camera.open();

        if (camera != null) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        Log.v(TAG, "surfaceChanged get called");

        if (previewing) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }

        if (camera != null) {
            try {

                 //new MainActivity().setCameraDisplayOrientation();

                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                // List<String> focusModes =
                // parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
                // if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO))
                // {
                // parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                // }

                List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();

                Camera.Size result = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
                    result = (Size) sizes.get(i);
                    Log.i("PictureSize", "Supported Size. Width: "
                            + result.width + "height : " + result.height);

                    if (result.width == 640) {
                        parameters.setPreviewSize(result.width, result.height);// 640*480
                        parameters.setPictureSize(result.width, result.height);
                    } else {

                    }
                }


                //**************************************************************//

                Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
                int rotation = display.getRotation();
                Log.v(TAG, "Current Device Orientation is ="+rotation);

                /* 
                 * Here is the logic I have added to Manage Camera Display Orientation
                 *  It checks Current Orientation and SDK and then rotate display to make it Portrait view.
                 */
                int currentSDKVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                Log.d(TAG, "currentVersion " + currentSDKVersion);

                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    if (currentSDKVersion != 7) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT +SDK is: " + currentSDKVersion
                                + "rotate 90");
                        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                         parameters.setRotation(90);
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT +SDK is: " + currentSDKVersion
                                + "rotate 90");
                        parameters.setRotation(90);

                        /*
                         * params.set("orientation", "portrait");
                         * params.set("rotation",90);
                         */
                    }
                } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    if (currentSDKVersion != 7) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE +SDK is: " + currentSDKVersion
                                + "rotate 90");

                        camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                    } else {

                        Log.i(TAG, "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE +SDK is: " + currentSDKVersion
                                + "rotate 90");

                        parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
                        parameters.set("rotation", 90);

                    }
                }


                //**************************************************************//


                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                camera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
                camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(cameraPreviewCallback);
                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        Log.v(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed get called");
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        previewing = false;

    }


    public void setCameraDisplayOrientation() 
    {        
        Log.v(TAG, "setCameraDisplayOrientation get called");

         if (camera == null)
         {
             Log.d(TAG,"setCameraDisplayOrientation - camera null");
             return;             
         }

         Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
         Camera.getCameraInfo(1, info);

         WindowManager winManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
         int rotation = winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

         int degrees = 0;

         switch (rotation) 
         {
             case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
             case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
             case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
             case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
         }

         int result;
         if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) 
         {
             result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
             result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
         } else {  // back-facing
             result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
         }
         camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onClick get called");

        if (v == buttonTakePicture) {
            camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW,
                    myPictureCallback_JPG);
        }

    }

    private Camera.PreviewCallback cameraPreviewCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreviewFrame size=" + data.length);
        }
    };

    AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
            Log.v(TAG, "onAutoFocus get called");
            buttonTakePicture.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };

    ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.v(TAG, "onShutter get called");
        }
    };

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
            Log.v(TAG, "onPictureTaken-RAW get called");

        }
    };

    public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
                source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
            Bitmap rawImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0,
                    arg0.length);

            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                Log.v(TAG, "#####  ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT   ####");

                rawImage = MainActivity.RotateBitmap(rawImage, 90);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                rawImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                arg0 = stream.toByteArray();

            } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                Log.v(TAG, "#####   ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE  #####");

            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("picture", arg0);
            startActivity(intent);

            Log.v(TAG, "onPictureTaken-JPG get called");

        }
    };

    /**
     * Get the size in bitmap.
     * 
     * @param bitmap
     * @return size in bytes
     */
    @TargetApi(12)
    public static int getBitmapSize(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (MainActivity.hasHoneycombMR1()) {
            return bitmap.getByteCount();
        }
        // Pre HC-MR1
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }

    public static boolean hasHoneycombMR1() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1;
    }

}
```

**Edit** : I have posted Comment on [Developer forum](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=1193) but no response.

Please!! Someone have any Idea regarding this problem.

I would really appreciate for any kind of suggestion.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using the manifest attribute `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`? You may want to give that a try, although I wouldn't really expect it to make any difference. Also, have you tried reproducing the issue in a 'bare' project - just to rule out that it's actually a device-specific issue rather than a potential implementation bug?

Comment: @MH. Dear! Thank for your comment. The above manifest tag I have added,which is for App Screen not Camera Preview Screen, btw tag is working fine so app screen is always in Portrait mode, but I want to rotate camera preview to be get rotate. Even I tried Java Reflection to Rotate manually,also checked all issues on Samsung developer site and Google android developer but no luck.

Comment: Hey RDC, did you figure it out at the end? it seems like no answer really works 100% ok, e.g: once trying most of the answer I can make Samsung phone works and the emulators as well but Nexus fails for example. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @RDC thanks for this very detailed question. Just for the record: absolutelly the same issue for HTC Sensation XE with Android 4.0.3. I am afraid I cannot change orientation to landscape too. Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @DmitryDzz .. no i did not get any work around for this issue.. even we have reported this to Samsung developers but no response yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I had a similar problem with the original Galaxy Tab running 2.2.1, I was able to solve it by doing the following:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
parameters.setRotation(90);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

However, it looks like you *may* have already tried that exact combination, given that you have identical (but commented out) code above. However, the way you have the code right now, the Ace is going to bypass where you have that commented code because of it's API level (10). Try it specifically inside this block:

```
if (currentSDKVersion != 7) { }
```

And let me know if it works, please. Thanks!

Comment: I updated as per your comment but still result preview remain same, its in landscape.

Comment: Thanks for the update; it's entirely possible that this is a bug with that particular handset and that there's no way to work around it. Wouldn't be the first time that a particular device had a unique bug. Also, it's fairly old at this point; is it a dealbreaker if this doesn't work on the Ace?

Comment: The method getParameters() is undefined for the type Camera

Comment: @Prasad please check the Android SDK here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getParameters()

It sounds like you're not correctly instantiating the camera.

Comment: I used this method but in portrait mode it shows stretched view in width (it looks that it shows landscape view in portrait)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a solution for hours too. Its really crazy.
My solution was to just use the camera preview in landscape mode (in my portrait app) and mask out the parts of the preview I don't need. I did this by overlaying upper and lower pars of my fullscreen preview with some views. Of cause you have to crop the photo you are getting from the camera then, WHICH RESULTS IN LESS RESOLUTION. For my app this was no issue.

I am totally happy with my solution now- users don't see any difference;

Comment: I totally agree with you,and respect your words.. but I am limited to Portrait mode only,because I need to send the result Image for Image Recognition So **if I lock to Landscape --> It'll require Rotate, Resize Image, Send Compressed Image while I have only few milli seconds for entire process, also It affects some sliding Animation, Coz Next screen is Portrait Locked. So Landscape --> Portrait Slide doesn't work..** so Ultimately I have to be in Portrait mode only at any cost. well Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

I have handled camera by writing some code that was majorly adapted from the ZXing project: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

You could try using those. If you are trying to use this, I would recommend going through the solution of this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252791/zxing-camera-in-portrait-mode-on-android)

This may not be the perfect solution to your question, but I had ran through this issue and had decided to use Zxing.